# Bootstrap3/CSS3 - Style Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-custom-search

Can you please give me advice how to style google custom searchbar on my webiste. Is it possible to style it with css3 and bootstrap3 as on picture below ? Thank you very much for help.

[image: MySearchbar/CSS3/Bootstrap3]

Comment: Not difficult, but if you don't know anything about CSS, I'd read a book or tutorial.  Do you know how to use bootstrap yet?  If not, that'd be your first step.  The above would be like a form group, and add an icon to the right portion.  Then define a custom class for the icon portion, and define it in your css.

Comment: @dcclassics I know CSS3 and Bootstrap3 classes, I just don't know how to style google custom searchbar to look same as on my picture above. Is there tutorial or something ? Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ujrrmch/ this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

HTML part:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group add-on">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default btnSubmit" type="submit" >
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS Part:

```
.add-on .input-group-btn > .btn {
    border-left-width:0;left:-2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

/* stop the glowing blue shadow */
.add-on .form-control:focus {
    box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none; 
    border-color:#cccccc; 
}

.btnSubmit {
    background: #FDD017;
}
```

The working [**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/XbiSysQ4zF)